# Sign change of coefficient in logistic regression when change from binomial to continuous predictor

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients

I am looking at the association between the application of animal control and population reduction. Population reduction is my outcome variable; it is a binomial variable where 1 = population reduction achieved, and 0 = population reduction not achieved. Animal control is my predictor variable and can be viewed in two different way; 1) control applied = 1 Vs control not applied = 0 (binomial variable); or 2) the number of times control was applied (continuous variable). I am using logistic regression to look at the association between the application of control and population reduction.

My model including animal control as a binomial variable produces a negative coefficient - i.e as the probability of animal control increases the probability of population reduction decreases. However, my model including animal control as a continuous variable produces a positive coefficient - i.e. for every unit increase in animal control the probability of population control increases. **How can this be possible?** **Are there any other common examples of when, where or how this can happen?**

I have read about sign change in logistic regression ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/regression-coefficients-that-flip-sign-after-including-other-predictors), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156780/sign-change-of-a-coefficient-in-logistic-regression), or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338789/predictor-flipping-sign-in-regression-with-no-multicollinearity)) as a result of the addition of multiple predictor variables into a model where the predictors are correlated to some extent. I could not find a question/answer explaining my above described situation, I would not think possible that it could be driven by correlation given only one variable is included in the model at any one time.

Comment: This can happen with a nonlinear effect from the predictor; try plotting the event rate vs this predictor?