# Logistic regression issue

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients

I am estimating a logistic regression model to investigate how various factors influence second-year college retention.  I include a variable indicating whether a student is in a minority racial-ethnic group and, as expected, find that this negatively impacts the probability of second-year retention.  However, when I introduce first-year GPA into the model, the sign of the minority variable flips —- minority status positively influences probability of retention.  I’m stumped.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This sounds like something called Simpson’s Paradox. Perhaps you will have some luck searching that term on here, as this is a topic that tricks pretty much everyone at some point.

Comment: @Sycorax This question has been asked and answered? [Regression coefficients that flip sign after including other predictors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/regression-coefficients-that-flip-sign-after-including-other-predictors)

Comment: @dipetkov That's a good example of a duplicate. You can vote to close questions as duplicates using the "Close" dialogue box.