Apartment Price dataset: Why are the coefficient signs different but not when conditioned on other values?
This question is similar to an open ended question a colleague asked...
Given the following regression:
$$\text{home_price} \sim \alpha + \beta_1 \cdot \text{sqft_living} + \beta_2 \cdot \text{bathrooms}$$
where $sign(\beta_1) = 1, sign(\beta_2) = -1$ in a prediction setting.
What is the reason for the signs differing? This is caused by colinearity...
To understand if it is meaningful, you can see how it performs out of sample and use variance regularization techniques.
Using the King County home price dataset, I see that $\alpha = -3.946e+04, \beta_1 = 283.8919, \beta_2 = -5164.6004$
What is odd to me is that when we do a PCA and regress PC1 and PC2 against price we get positive coefficients...even if I inverse standardize the PCA's...
price ~ sqft_living and bathrooms
|       |       r2 |   intercept |   beta_sqft_living |   beta_bathrooms |
|:------|---------:|------------:|-------------------:|-----------------:|
| value | 0.492904 |    -39456.6 |            283.892 |          -5164.6 |

price ~ pc1 and pc2
|       |       r2 |   intercept |   beta_pc1 |   beta_pc2 |
|:------|---------:|------------:|-----------:|-----------:|
| value | 0.492904 |      540088 |     181553 |     187178 |

price ~ inverse standardized pc1 and pc2
|       |       r2 |   intercept |   beta_pc1_i |   beta_pc2_i |
|:------|---------:|------------:|-------------:|-------------:|
| value | 0.492904 |     -385041 |       197.68 |       243042 |

price ~ bathrooms
|       |       r2 |   intercept |   beta_bathrooms |
|:------|---------:|------------:|-----------------:|
| value | 0.275769 |     10708.3 |           250327 |

price ~ sqft_living
|       |       r2 |   intercept |   beta_sqft_living |
|:------|---------:|------------:|-------------------:|
| value | 0.492853 |    -43580.7 |            280.624 |

sqft_living ~ bathrooms
|       |      r2 |   intercept |   beta_bathrooms |
|:------|--------:|------------:|-----------------:|
| value | 0.56952 |     176.704 |          899.959 |

price ~ sqft_living and bathrooms filtering on bedrooms == 2
|       |      r2 |   intercept |   beta_sqft_living |   beta_bathrooms |
|:------|--------:|------------:|-------------------:|-----------------:|
| value | 0.39274 |     66400.4 |            263.848 |          5612.01 |

The above regression (filtering on bedroom) is odd... I see that corr(sqft_living, bathrooms
| bedroom=2) =  .56 and corr(sqft_living, bathrooms) =  0.75
Questions:

Why is $sign(\beta_1) = 1, sign(\beta_2) = -1$ in the full regression? How an you explain this intuitively?
I assume this is from the strong correlation of the variables and since they are correlated sqft_living room is capturing the size component and bathrooms is correcting for any errors. But I don't understand why the PC results don't show this idea...

Is it a problem and at what point is the correlation of two variables in a regression with two variables and issue? I assume not and it really depends on test set performance

What is an intuitive understanding for why $sign(\beta_1| \text{bedrooms}=2) = 1, sign(\beta_2 | \text{bedrooms}=2) = 1$?


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def get_results(df, X_train_columns=['sqft_living', 'bathrooms'], y_train_column="price"):
    model = LinearRegression().fit(df[X_train_columns], df[y_train_column])
    results = []
    results.append(["r2", model.score(df[X_train_columns], df[y_train_column])])
    results.append(["intercept", model.intercept_])
    for col, coef in zip(X_train_columns, model.coef_):
        results.append(["beta_"+col, coef])
    df_result = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=["measure", "value"]).set_index("measure")
    return df_result.T

# https://www.openml.org/search?type=data&status=active&id=42092
# This dataset contains house sale prices for King County, which includes Seattle. It includes homes sold between May 2014 and May 2015.
data = fetch_openml(data_id=42092)
df = data['frame']

ss = StandardScaler()
pca_pl = Pipeline([('scaling', ss), ('pca', PCA(n_components=2))])

df_sub = df[['sqft_living', 'bathrooms']]
df_sub[['pc1', 'pc2']] = pca_pl.fit_transform(df_sub)
df_sub[['pc1_i', 'pc2_i']] = ss.inverse_transform(df_sub[['pc1', 'pc2']])
df_sub["price"] = df["price"]
df_sub["bedrooms"] = df["bedrooms"]

print("price ~ sqft_living and bathrooms")
print(get_results(df_sub).to_markdown())
print("price ~ pc1 and pc2")
print(get_results(df_sub, X_train_columns=['pc1', 'pc2']).to_markdown())
print("price ~ inverse standardized pc1 and pc2")
print(get_results(df_sub, X_train_columns=['pc1_i', 'pc2_i']).to_markdown())
print("price ~ bathrooms")
print(get_results(df_sub, X_train_columns=['bathrooms']).to_markdown())
print("price ~ sqft_living")
print(get_results(df_sub, X_train_columns=['sqft_living']).to_markdown())
print("sqft_living ~ bathrooms")
print(get_results(df_sub, X_train_columns=['bathrooms'], y_train_column="sqft_living").to_markdown())
print("price ~ sqft_living and bathrooms filtering on bedrooms == 2")
print(get_results(df_sub.query("bedrooms==2")).to_markdown())
```


This reads like a question about housing prices, concerning your expectations about relationships between house features and price.  What is the statistical content?

What are the reasons for these sign differences? Why when conditioning on bedrooms are the signs the same. The data example is to help provide insight into the theoretical question.

That's a FAQ with many good answers: please search our site

But why when conditioning on bedrooms are the signs the same... that's the part I am missing

For your question 1, bathrooms is not "correcting for errors". It is simply that, at a given size, having more bathrooms is associated with a lower price.PCA with only two variables seems rather odd.
For your question 2, you can look at condition indexes or at variance inflation factors.
For your question 3, with two bedrooms, more space is associated with higher price, as are more bathrooms. That makes perfect sense. People like more space per bedroom and people like having a bathroom for every bedroom.

your answer 3 seems to contradict answer to 1

I don't see a contradiction, but I would like to suggest that in a multiple regression, once square footage is accounted for, the bathroom count really represents number of bedrooms relative to what would be predicted from the house size.  Anticipating a strong correlation between size and bathrooms, we would say that size already prices in the bathrooms.

"at a given size, having more bathrooms is associated with a lower price."  But with two bedrooms this is not the case...why? I am not asking to interpret the regression results. This is a toy example to try to understand reasons why the coefficients in one case have the same sign but when conditioned on 2 bedrooms they don't

I don't see any way to answer this other than interpreting the regression results. And my answers do not contradict each other, they really have nothing to do with each other. The first does not deal with number of bedrooms.

Your answer for number 2 is not really correct. You can look at VIF, but there is no threshold that says it is actually an issue... Really you want to look on your test set performance...  For the difference when controlling for bedroom vs full model, is it possible Simpson paradox is at play? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/regression-coefficients-that-flip-sign-after-including-other-predictors

Yes, there are thresholds. See e.g. Penn State page https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat462/node/180/  For condition indices, see either of David Belsley's books or my dissertation "Collinearity Diagnostics in Multiple Regression: A Monte Carlo study".

Also, looking at test set performance will NOT help with collinearity. If the train and test sets are randomly chosen, the test set will have the same issues.
